# Can I make Thunderbird notify me of incoming spam?

Tags: thunderbird

When I receive a new email in Thunderbird, it plays a sound and shows a toast in the bottom-right corner notifying me. However, this doesn't happen if the email arrives in a 'Spam' or 'Junk' folder.

[image: Thunderbird notification screenshot]

Is there a way to change this so that Thunderbird will always notify me like this, even for spam emails?

(Thunderbird 115.2.3 64-bit)

Comment: That is undoubtedly a question for Thunderbird.  I isolate and deal with spam before Outlook sees anything

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be notified of spam is to disable its detection.
This is done in *Settings > General > Privacy & Security* under
"Scam Detection".

You would then need an alternative software to detect your spam
before it arrives to Thunderbird, rather than using the Thunderbird
spam filter.

Answer (score 0):

This has been [answered](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1269501) by Mozilla support: Right-click the Junk folder, Properties, check the box 'When getting new messages...'.